# Inherited Knockout template that I cannot get working

Tags: knockout.js

I am a new dev at my work and inherited this code as my first project. This code is working in the app, but when I try and manually add values it breaks, and I don't understand why.

The template code is the pre-existing piece, and the rest is me trying to implement it.

Here is the code:

```
<p>Rate: <strong data-bind="text: rate"></strong></p>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'percentage-template', data: { data: rate, enable: secure }}"></div> 

<script type="text/html" id="percentage-template">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" 
        class="form-control" 
        data-bind="vale: data, 
                precision: precision || 2, 
                isPercent: isPercent || true, 
                enable: enable || true"
        />
        <span class="input-group-addon">%</span>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyViewModel() {     
        this.rate = ko.observable(.01);
        this.secure = ko.observable(false);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

Here is the view portion that is working in the app:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'percentage-template', data: {data: Form.Current.Rate, enable: ViewSecurity.Edit}}"></div>
```

The problem is that when using the template, the input box remains empty and does not show rate.

EDIT: I changed the custom binding within the template to value, thanks bryan
I also made the values observables

Comment: not really following your question however should rate and or secure be observables? second numeric is not a default knockout binding so there must be a custom numeric binding somewhere can you show that?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I tried in the past with those being observables without success, but i should probably leave them that way..!

I didn't realize numeric wasn't a native binding, and i found it but it's 66 lines long. Let me delve into that more and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template is set up to bind to 'data', and in your case you're passing 'rate' into that binding, but 'rate' is not set up as an observable so it's only going to get the initial value from your model and there won't be a two-way binding to catch updates. If you want changes entered into the text-input to update the 'rate' variable on your model then you need to make rate an observable.

```
this.rate = ko.observable(.01);
```